# How do I change the Wallpaper Style in Windows 7 locked down by domain group policy?

Tags: windows-7, group-policy, desktop-customization

my computer has been controlled by a domain group policy. However, I've managed to set my desktop background by insert the image file into the path under the registry and change the file name to the name of default background image. I also managed to change the wallpaper style (i prefer 4(fill) to correctly display my wallpaper) but it will change back to default which is 2(stretch) each time i switch on and logon to the computer. My question is there anyway i can fix this wallpaper style to 4(fill) so that it wont go back to default each time i shut down and switch on my computer back?

Thanks,
Ally.

Comment: You don't, and attempts to circumvent policies is often grounds for firing. So stop, please.

Answer (score 0):

Putting to one side any moral judgments for a second, this is actually quite an interesting challenge.

Look at the dimensions of your image and also at the native resolution of the monitor. Your goal is to create a modified version of your image that will fit the monitor perfectly, so that choosing different display options will have no effect on the image.

1. Open MS Paint and set your canvas to the exact same dimensions as the computer monitor.
2. Paste your image onto the canvas.
3. Resize the image so that it's large enough that all of the canvas is completely covered by your image. This is effectively a fill!
4. Save the image and use this modified version of your background image instead.

This spoon feeds Windows with an image of identical height and width, so choosing `Fit` will no longer have any effect.